# SQL - duplicate tags coming back when more than one left join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, tags, left-join

I'm fetching a booking, with multiple linked tags and customers attached to that booking.

There are two intermediary tables which exist to track associations between other tables: `tag_assocs` between the `bookings` (in this case) and `tags` table, and `assocs` between the `bookings` and `customers` tables.

SQL (simplified):

```
SELECT
    bookings.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tag SEPARATOR "|") AS tags,
    GROUP_CONCAT(customers.id SEPARATOR "|") AS customer_id
FROM bookings
LEFT JOIN tag_assocs ON tag_assocs.item_id = bookings.id && tag_assocs.item_type = "bookings"
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tag_assocs.tag_id
LEFT JOIN assocs ON assocs.item_id = bookings.id && assocs.item_type = "bookings.customer_id"
LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.id = assocs.foreign_item_id
WHERE bookings.id = "a64l_ku-4af"
GROUP BY bookings.id
ORDER BY bookings.modified desc
LIMIT 20
```

Now, the booking in question (a64l_ku-4af) has only one tag - confirmed in the DB. That is to say, it has just one entry in `tag_assocs` for the tag `some-tag`. Indeed, this is enforced by a unique index blocking duplication. But it's coming back twice, i.e.

```
--------------------
| tags             |
--------------------
| some-tag|some-tag|
--------------------
```

**Two-part question:**

1) Why is this?

2) I can fix this by changing `GROUP_CONCAT(tag ...` to `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag ...)` but I get the feeling that's a hack and doesn't address the cause of the issue.

Comment: Have a look at the result without GROUP BY and without GROUP_CONCAT, then you'll understand. And no: 2) is not an hack. Every join that produces more than one row for an already existing row will produce as much rows in the result set and multiply the occurrences of your tags accordingly.

Comment: @VMai - I was assuming 2) was a hack because I presume MySQL handles DISTINCT by first getting all rows and then removing duplicates. If so, this is an overhead I was thinking I should try to avoid.

Comment: Yes, I can understand your reasoning. I assumed something in this line. Because of that I decided to explain it by a comprehensible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's explain with an example. Assuming we have the following tables:

**Part 1: the original query**

Table books:

```
id | book
------------
 1 | Book 1
 2 | Book 2
```

Table tags:

```
id | tag
-----------
 1 | Hobby
 2 | Sport
 3 | Work
```

Table books2tags (for tagging books with appropriate tags):

```
book_id | tag_id
----------------
      1 |     1
      1 |     2
      2 |     2
      2 |     3
```

Now both books have got two tags attached and the result of

```
SELECT b.book, t.tag FROM books b
INNER JOIN books2tags bt ON b.id = bt.book_id
INNER JOIN tags t ON bt.tag_id = t.id
```

will be like that (the order is irrelevant):

```
book   | tag
---------------
book 1 | Hobby
book 1 | Sport
book 2 | Sport
book 2 | Work
```

To get a string with the list of tags for every book, we use

```
SELECT b.book, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag SEPARATOR '|') as tags FROM books b
INNER JOIN books2tags bt ON b.id = bt.book_id
INNER JOIN tags t ON bt.tag_id = t.id
GROUP BY b.book
```

and the result may be:

```
book   | tags
---------------------
book 1 | Hobby|Sport
book 2 | Work|Sport
```

**Part 2: joining another table**

If we have another table with optional additional information, let's say example:

```
id | book_id | example
-------------------------------------
 1 |      1  | 'example information'
 2 |      2  | 'another example'
```

the we get this additional information with a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT b.book, t.tag, e.example FROM books b
INNER JOIN books2tags bt ON b.id = bt.book_id
INNER JOIN tags t ON bt.tag_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN example e ON b.id = e.book_id
```

The result will be:

```
book   | tag     | example
----------------------------
book 1 | Hobby   | example information
book 1 | Hobby   | another example
book 1 | Sport   | example information
book 1 | Sport   | another example
book 2 | Sport   | NULL
book 2 | Work    | NULL
```

You see that every row for book 1 from our original query will be as often in the result as there are matching rows in our newly joined table example. If we use our old query to get the tags by book, but with the added left join we'll get by

```
SELECT b.book, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag SEPARATOR '|') as tags FROM books b
INNER JOIN books2tags bt ON b.id = bt.book_id
INNER JOIN tags t ON bt.tag_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN example e ON b.id = e.book_id
GROUP BY b.book

book   | tags
---------------------
book 1 | Hobby|Hobby|Sport|Sport
book 2 | Work|Sport
```

That's because there are two rows with the tag 'Hobby' and two rows with the tag 'Sport' now. But to get the list of the tags, we get the right result by using DISTINCT. That's not a hack:

```
SELECT b.book, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag SEPARATOR '|') as tags FROM books b
INNER JOIN books2tags bt ON b.id = bt.book_id
INNER JOIN tags t ON bt.tag_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN example e ON b.id = e.book_id
GROUP BY b.book

book   | tags
---------------------
book 1 | Hobby|Sport
book 2 | Work|Sport
```

**Conclusion**

I think I demonstrated why the tags can get duplicated by joining another table as answer to part 1 of your question and can assure you that your solution is not a hack, but in fact the right solution for this issue.

Have a look at **[this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3aab5/4)** too.

Comment: Wow, great answer. Thanks for going to such length to help me. Exemplifies the very best of SO. +1 and accepted.